# Geolocation how to get address from random string

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Bassicly im using the geolocation function in google maps in order to convert a address to cordinates.

I understand how to do this and i got it working correctly but this is based on user input so if a user typed in random information such as "NW1 hello blabla", isit possible to get google maps to read the string and notice which words are an actual address.

***Geolocation code***

```
var place =  "New York Hello"; // I want to enter any kind of string and have gmaps to understand it

geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

geocoder.getLatLng(place, function(point) {  (!point) {

alert(place + " not found");
} else {

var info = "<h3>"+place+"</h3>Latitude: "+point.y+"  Longitude:"+point.x;

var marker = new GMarker(point);

map.addOverlay(marker);

marker.openInfoWindowHtml(info);
} });
```

Comment: why negative rating at least know the answer before you judge it lol

Comment: Your code looks like Google Maps API v2 (despite you tagging this google-maps-api-3), which is deprecated and will stop working completely in May 2013. You should upgrade to API v3.

Comment: I think your question is impossible to do, at least without a very hefty regular expression.  How do you define what an address looks like?  in your first example, two of the three words are a place name.  In your second example, two letters and a digit = a postcode.  How would you define what could be an address string from `"xy9 foo bar blah ab1 abc xyz blablah"`?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the geocoder is designed to do (get a string that looks like an address and return a location, but not a "random" string).  But if the user types in garbage, you get garbage out.  If the string looks like an address (and there is an entry that matches), the geocoder does a reasonable job.